# Short Question on Case sensitivity; Php

Tags: php, html, regex

This tests a textarea input agains bad words...

```
$bad_words = array('bad', 'words')

foreach( $bad_words as $bad ){
 if( stristr($posted, $bad) !== FALSE )
 {
  $contains_bad_words = TRUE;
 }    
}
```

Now is there any way to make this match 'bad', 'BAD', 'Bad', 'BaD' etc without having to write it into the array in all different cases (Large letters, small letters)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that should do it. `strstr` is case-sensitive, and `stristr` is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
strstr() is case-sensitive. For case-insensitive searches, use stristr().
```

http://us.php.net/strstr

Answer (score 0):

$bad_words = array('bad', 'words');
foreach($bad_words as $bad) if(preg_match("/$bad/i",$posted)) $contains_bad_words = TRUE;